# Shiny server systemctl fails at boot

Tags: boot, systemd, r

I installed [Shiny Server](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) on my Ubuntu Mate 15.10 64bit.

I can start the server without problem after boot by running manually the command `sudo systemctl start shiny-server`.

I enabled the service to start at boot with 
`sudo systemctl enable shiny-server`, but when I boot the server is not started.

I did `sudo systemctl status shiny-server` and the log says that starting the server failed with error:

```
pid file /var/run/shiny-server.pid not readable (yet?)
```

How can I fix such an issue?

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same problem on a RHEL 7.x box...

We are waiting on an official response from the shiny-server gurus.

However, for the time being, if you edit the `/etc/systemd/system/shiny-server.service` file...and comment out the`PIDFile=/var/run/shiny-server.pid` line, it seems to 'fix' the problem.

(you may need to translate paths since I'm on en EL 7 box, and you are on an Ubuntu Server)

Comment: Did you ever hear of an official solution to this issue? I just hit the exact same one on Ubuntu 16.04, and your fixed worked for me for the moment.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue when I downgraded from a Pro evaluation version to the free one. Commenting that line out, running `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and restarting the server seemed to do the trick.

But I don't know why....